# ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCount$TokenizerMapper not found, when running Hadoop3alpha in pseudo mode

Tags: hadoop, classnotfound

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 and have installed Hadoop3.0.0Alpha1 in single node cluster (pseudo distributed mode). I am trying to run simple word count program. When I run the program without yarn, it works. But when I run it using yarn, I am getting class not found exception. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        //job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
```

This WordCount class has 2 inner classes - TokenizerMapper adn IntSumReader which extends Mappper and Reducer resp. I am running this using the command

> bin/hadoop jar /WordCount.jar WordCount input/word_count/books/*  output/word_count_v2

The error that I get is

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Class WordCount$TokenizerMapper not found

When I do jar -tf WordCount.jar I can see all classes in it. I have tried almost all possible suggestions mentioned online including,

1. After setting the JarClass add job.waitForCompletion(true);
   Doing so executed the program but at the end gives an Illegal State error that Node is in Running state rather than Define.Because of which I guess I am not able to see the output in required format. I read the documentation, it says that first you need to set the values and then submit the job else it is likely to get this error.
2. Set job.setJar();
   When I do this I get JAR not found exception.
3. Tried setting Classpath and HadoopClasspath too but no luck.

I am not sure where Hadoop looks to get all the class files.

Comment: Does the output of "jar -tvf" on WordCount.jar show this class as part of JAR file ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I can see all required classes part of this jar.